# How to get minimize/restore/close rectangle?

Tags: qt, mdi

I want to draw some text in the end of menu bar like this
[image]

But when the child window is maximized in the MDI project it looks like this
[image]
I need to fix this output.
I want to check if the active child is maximized and if it is I want to get minimize/restore/close rectangle to get them total width.
How can I get active child window and how can I get it's rectangle of buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// in yourMainWindow.cpp

...

```
auto child = mdiArea->addSubWindow(yourWidget);
connect(child, &QMdiSubWindow::windowStateChanged, this, &yourMainWindow::yourSlot);
```

...

```
void yourMainWindow::yourSlot(Qt::WindowStates oldState, Qt::WindowStates newState)
{
    if (newState.testFlag(Qt::WindowMaximized)) {
        auto child = qobject_cast<QMdiSubWindow *>(sender());
        if (!child)
            return;

        QStyleOptionComplex opt;
        opt.initFrom(child);

        auto size = child->style()->sizeFromContents(QStyle::CT_MdiControls, &opt, QSize(100, 20));
        qDebug() << size;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `QSize(100, 20)`?