# How to set cursor when it is in some area?

Tags: qt, qtgui, mouse-cursor

I have some rectangle link area on my widget. What is the best way to make cursor `Qt::PointingHandCursor` when it is in this area?
[image]

Comment: How are you handling the interaction on the link area without it being a child widget?

Comment: I draw text and handle click signal. My problem is no widget leaved signal so when I move cursor up it stays override cursor. Actually I want to make a link in the right part of menu bar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433958/how-to-get-minimize-restore-close-rectangle

Comment: may be you know how can I add a widget to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `QWidget` class has a `cursor` property that you can set with the cursor you wish displayed when the mouse is above it.

EDIT:
Without more detail on what you are trying to achieve, I can only assume you're making your life much more difficult than it needs to be. You can create a `QLabel` widget to handle the link and then place the label on the menubar automatically.

```
QLabel *link = new QLabel("<a href='http://doc.qt.io'>Qt Documentation</a>");
menuBar()->setCornerWidget(link);
```

All the text formatting, cursor display and user interactions are handled by existing code in the `Qt` classes. The only thing you need to do yourself is to handle what happens when the user clicks on the link, that you can do by connecting a slot to the `QLabel::linkActivated(const QString &)` signal.

Comment: `myWidget.setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);`